# SOSL query searching in multiple fields

Tags: soql, sosl

I want to search in multiple fields using SOSL. I know that it allows to search in all fields using below syntax-

```
FIND {"Smith"} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING contact (name), lead (name)
```

And also works perfectly fine with single field if I supply any field's name instead of ALL like below-

```
FIND {"Smith"} IN Name FIELDS RETURNING contact (name), lead (name)
```

What I want to try is something like below-

```
FIND {"Smith"} IN (NAME, COMPANY) FIELDS RETURNING contact (name), lead (name)
```

I have tried various things here for IN (NAME, COMPANY) like below-

- IN NAME, COMPANY
- IN {NAME, COMPANY}
- IN NAME; COMPANY

Can someone please suggest if there is a way of doing it in SOSL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't specify individual fields this way. The only [options](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_syntax.htm) for IN X FIELDS are:

- ALL FIELDS
- NAME FIELDS
- EMAIL FIELDS
- PHONE FIELDS
- SIDEBAR FIELDS

If you'd like, you can provide filters on the individual objects, such as:

```
FIND :term IN ALL FIELDS
RETURNING Lead(Name, Company WHERE Name LIKE :filter OR Company LIKE :filter)...
```